# Why Write IOPS,Write throughput,Queue depth decreased on AWS/RDS after changing innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit and sync_binlog?

Tags: mysql, innodb, amazon-rds, performance, performance-tuning

I changed values for my Mysql parameters

**1.** **innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2(before it was 1)**

**2.** **sync_binlog=0(before it was 1)**

This has changed some of my parameters on AW RDS drastically ,here are some of them.

> **Write Operations(Count/sec)**

[image]

> **Queue Depth**

[image]

My question is ,What can i interpret from the above results ? Is is good for my database ? Is the performance increased ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those changes improved throughput, but decreased robustness.

`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1` says to flush stuff to disk at every `COMMIT`, thereby making your database fully crash-proof.  `=2` risks one second's worth of `COMMITs`.

If you have the binlog turned on, `sync_binlog=1` says to flush to disk at every `COMMIT`.  `=0` allows delaying (buffering) the writes.  This variable is somewhat important if you have Slaves and/or do incremental backups.

Comment: There is a drastic decrease in the write operations .Is it good/bad for my DB performance  ?

Comment: Define "performance".  It seemed that performance was OK before.  Or was it sluggish?  If anything, these changes allow you to have many more connections doing more stuff.  The main slowdown in MySQL is I/O; the changes decreased the I/O.

Comment: By database performance I mean , the optimization of resource used to increase throughput and minimize contention, enabling the largest possible workload to be processed.

Comment: The setting change led to optimization of the I/O resource.  So, from that point of view, a greater workload can be handled.  Of course, some other bottleneck should show up next.  Still, as your graphs show, there is a significant improvement.